# Setting API Parameters with State Management Issue

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on a ReactNative project and I am having trouble setting the states correctly and having them pass into my API call.

Would anyone care to help?

[Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u436K.png)

```
const {
    playerName,
    selectedStat,
    selectedLine: initialSelectedLine, // Rename to avoid variable name conflict
    selectedPlay,
    projection,
    team,
    opp,
  } = route.params;

  // State to hold the fetched data
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  // State to hold x-axis labels
  const [xLabels, setXLabels] = useState([]);

  // States to hold API filters
  const [numGames, setNumGames] = useState(10);
  const [oppChoice, setOppChoice] = useState([]);
  const [min_min, setmin_min] = useState([]);
  const [max_min, setmax_min] = useState([]);

  // Use initialSelectedLine as the initial value for selectedLine
  const [selectedLine, setSelectedLine] = useState(initialSelectedLine);

  // Function to update the chart data and x-axis labels when the parameters are changed
  const updateChartData = (numGames) => {
    // Clear existing data and labels
    setData([]);
    setXLabels([]);

    // Fetch player game logs based on the player's name and the selected parameters
    fetch(
      `https://dummy-api-link.com/all-gamelogs?player=${playerName}&games=${numGames}&sort=desc&opp=${oppChoice}`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        // Extract PTS values from the fetched data and store in newData
        const newData = responseData.GameLogs.map((log) => ({
          value: parseInt(log[statMapping[selectedStat]]),
        }));

        // Extract x-axis labels (dates) from the fetched data
        const newLabels = responseData.GameLogs.map(
          (log) => log[statMapping[selectedStat]]
        );

        // Update the states with the new data and labels
        setData(newData);
        setXLabels(newLabels);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching game logs:", error));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Initial fetch and update of chart data and labels when the component mounts
    updateChartData(numGames);
  }, [playerName, numGames, selectedStat]);

  return (
      {/* Game options */}
      <View style={styles.gameOptionsContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.gameOptionButton}>
          <Text style={styles.gameOptionText}>ALL</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.gameOptionButton}
          onPress={() => {
            setNumGames(5);
            updateChartData(5); // Fetch and update data for 5 games
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.gameOptionText}>L5</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.gameOptionButton}
          onPress={() => {
            setNumGames(10);
            updateChartData(10); // Fetch and update data for 10 games
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.gameOptionText}>L10</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.gameOptionButton}
          onPress={() => {
            setNumGames(20);
            updateChartData(20); // Fetch and update data for 15 games
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.gameOptionText}>L20</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.gameOptionButton}>
          <Text style={styles.gameOptionText}>{opp}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.gameOptionButton}>
          <Text style={styles.gameOptionText}>
            <Ionicons name="filter" size={20} color="white" />
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

Here is a simulator screenshot and my code block (this isn't everything, I just deleted what wasn't important)

Essentially what I want to do is select each All, L5, L10, L20, and {opp} touchable opacitiy and set the appropriate API parameters.

- For example if we select All, then it must set numGames=null, if we select L5, numGames=5, etc.

However, when we click the button {opp} we must set the numGames=null and oppChoice={opp} which is the passed in opp parameter from the previous page.

Any guidance would be amazing!

Thanks!